# Conditional remove table row on jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have some table

```
  <table>
  <tr class="trclass">
  <td class ="tdc">
  <img src="/images/products/nophoto_s.jpg">
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

How to remove table row if img src tag not include nophoto_s.jpg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` can take a function allowing you to specify any condition you'd like.  Use this, with `find`, to grab all table rows that have an image with `nophoto_s.jpg` as the `src`, then remove them.

```
$("tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("img[src*='nophoto_s.jpg']").length > 0;
}).remove();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GduTP/)

Comment: q = $("tr").find("img[src*='nophoto_s.jpg'").length > 0;  q is false;

Comment: @Victor - not sure I follow.  Does the fiddle I attached not demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: I call function in $(document).ready(function(){ //here  }); Probably so, and does not work. How to resolve this trouble?

Comment: @Victor - I don't know what you're asking.  The fiddle I attached shows how to remove table rows that have this image.  Just put the code that's in that button click handler wherever you need it to run