# Unable to pass data from javascript to json

Tags: javascript, json, servlets, handsontable

I want to pass data from hands on table to servlet . I have tried a method in which I am able to get the data when iItry to pass to servlet I am not able to get the data from `request.getParameter("forecastdata");` which is null. Please tell what is the mistake in my code
**ArrayToJson**

```
@WebServlet("/arrayToJson/*")
public class ArrayToJson extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        request.getParameter("forecastdata");
        ;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#divButtons").find(".btnSubmit").click(function () {
    console.log($container.data('handsontable').getData());
   var forecast=$container.data('handsontable').getData()
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Pj_IFRS_P5/arrayToJson",
        data: {
            forecastdata: forecast
        }, //returns all cells' data
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result === 'ok') {
                console.log('Data saved');
            } else {
                console.log('Save error');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your  own server to see the success message.');
        }
    });
});

$("#handsontable").handsontable(config);


});
```

[image]

Comment: what does it prints for this line "console.log($container.data('handsontable').getData());"

Comment: it prints the data value

Comment: MY question now is how to conditionally disable row in handsontable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're using jquery you can check your condition and disable the row fully by using a filter. there are lot of examples out there and even in stackoverflow .

one example and fiddle is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638545/conditional-remove-table-row-on-jquery)

if that is your case now, this might answer it !

Comment: I Achieved it by giving this code if(this.instance.getDataAtCell(row, 0) != '--Forecast'){
      cellProperties.readOnly = true;   
         }

Comment: i want to know how to restrict fields in handsontable with currency